# Azure Blob: How to grant a mobile app limited access to user-specific data

Tags: azure-blob-storage

I have a mobile app (Xamarin Android & iOS) that connects to a website (ASP.NET MVC). Some of the content for the mobile app (files & images) comes from an Azure Blob store that currently has public read-access enabled.

I am building an authentication module for the app (OAuth, with username/password). Is it possible to somehow build authentication into my Azure Blob account as well, so that a user would only have access to their specific files?  I know that I could use the website as an intermediary (ie. user authenticates and connects to website, websites connects to azure & retrieves data and returns it to app) but this will add an extra step of lag as opposed to just connecting to Azure Blob directly.

I see that Azure Blob supports a shared access signature (SAS) tokens. Is it possible to generate a SAS token just for the subset of files relevant to that user? I imagine the workflow would be:

1. mobile app authenticates to website api
2. website generates and return SAS token for blob access
3. mobile app connects to azure blob directly using SAS token.

Would that even be a good idea? Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand of your scenario, you could use either Azure AD or SAS for authentication/authorization to Blob storage. The key will be to organize your users' data by container, so that you can restrict access to that container. This type of design will align best with how authorization is handled in Azure Storage today.

So for example, you would create a container for user1's data, another container for user2's data, and so on.

If you are already using Azure AD to authenticate and authorize your users for your application, then you may be able to simply assign an RBAC role that is scoped to the user's container for each user. For example, you can assign the **Storage Blob Data Contributor** role to user1 for container1, then do the same for user2 on container2. See [Use the Azure portal to assign an Azure role for access to blob and queue data](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-rbac-portal?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json) for information about how to do this in the Azure portal; you can also use PowerShell or Azure CLI.

Note that an RBAC role cannot be scoped to an individual blob, but only at the container level or above.

If you determine that you need to use SAS, you can create a SAS for each user that is restricted to their container. If your users are already authenticating/authorizing to your application with Azure AD, then you probably don't need to use SAS. The SAS would be useful in the case where you need to grant access to a user that is not otherwise authenticated.